# Using chsh to switch to a csh shell from bash,

Tags: logout, scripts

People keep saying you need to logout and log back in for chsh to take effect but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.  Logout doesn't work; it tells me to use exit.  Exit closes the terminal but when I open a new terminal nothing has changed.  Do I need to reboot my whole system?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to change the shell being used when you use your terminal emulator (such as urxvt, gnome-terminal, xterm) or when you use the console. My assumption is that you're logged into a graphical environment such as gnome-shell/unity/etc. and `exit` just closes your terminal emulator window and quite rightly so.

Try logging out of your X session and then back in. `exit` would have worked if you were logged in using a console (most likely tty1-6, accessible via CTRL+ALT+F1-6). Of course it would have worked but only for that and the following console sessions - it wouldn't influence your already running X session's behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`logout` works only when you use `tty` - computer terminal accessible from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd>. This is probably not what you want.

If you want to log-out from `Unity` desktop you need to either:

- log-out through GUI (power button in the top right hand side corner
  or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing in `Log Out` in the Unity
  HUD)
- or run `gnome-session-quit` in terminal emulator (like gnome-terminal).

---

Yeah, reboot would work too :)